# Django forms, referencing foreignkey model in view

Tags: python, django

I want to display a form in Django that loads a list of ForeignKeys so that the user can select one category. However, my code asks for a text input instead of a ForeignKey. I don't know how to tell the form to load the list of Foreign Keys instead of a text.

models.py

```
class Userdata(models.Model):
    """docstring for Userdata"""
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

I'm using a Foreign Key instance

```
def profiler(request):
    userdata = models.Userdata()
    userdata.category = request.POST('category')             
    userdata.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('success')
```

Html form

```
   <form class="col m6 offset-m3 s12 form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

Comment: You mentioned using a form, where's your form?

Comment: @ShangWang Form is on html, I think I need to load a context dict to populate the Option field but don't know how to add the value to a category

Comment: In django people don't make forms by hand. Check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: Walk through the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/ it's quite short and you will know the answer by the end of it (and much more)

Comment: @ShangWang Even if I'm working with external css libraries and don't want the default widget? I'm using MaterializeCss

Comment: @Juanvulcano even if you're using Materialize you'll still want to use Django forms for templating because it performs validation and type casting for you to properly save models.  You'll want to use a ModelForm and if you want to use Materialize you'll want to use manual field rendering instead of nothing but plain HTML handling and parsing.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually